# How to add java runtime parameters in MyEclipse?

Tags: java, parameters, javac, myeclipse

To do this in the command line, first I put:

```
javac -classpath .;i:\jmsl\jmsl4.0\lib\jmsl.jar Jmsl.java
```

Now I have `Jmsl`, and then I execute the program by:

```
java -Dcom.imsl.license.path=i:\jmsl\license\license.dat -cp .;i:\jmsl\jmsl4.0\lib\jmsl.jar Jmsl
```

And now I want to run all above in MyEclipse, how can I do that? How to add necessary parameters in MyEclipse?

Comment: Have you tried instructions for normal eclipse? Add `i:\jmsl\jmsl4.0\lib\jmsl.jar` to build path of your project, and set parameters of your class in `run->run configurations->arguments`?

Answer (score 2):

Just right of your "run" icon there is an small arrow, from there you can access the "Run Configurations" screen. You can create (or modify) an existing run configuration (which mostly references to a class which has a main on it) and:

- Add a VM argument `-Dcom.imsl.license.path=i:\jmsl\license\license.dat` in the "Arguments" tab
- Regarding your -cp (classpath) argument... that will be set automatically by eclipse. If you want to add a jar in there you will need to do it from the "Classpath" tab (or if your jar is already referenced through your project build path then no change is needed)
- Jmsl is "Program Argument" and you can set that through the Arguments tab too

Answer (score 0):

We can add the run time variables by editing the run time configurations in Eclipse.

Steps :

Go to RUN Menu > Run Configurations.

Navigate to the second tab "Arguments"

Add all the required variables sepearted by a "< SPACE >"

Select the Workspace in the bottom of the dialogue

Click on "Apply" and then close.

Now to access the parameters we can call args[0], args[1] ....

like :

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }`

Note : the data retieved thus is in the String format